# How does MySQL handle indexes and where clauses with joins

Tags: mysql, join, where

I am querying large tables with joins and where conditions.

An example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM forename
JOIN forenameLength ON forenameLength.nameRef = forename.nameRef
WHERE forename.placeRef = 18000 AND forenameLength.length = 3
```

Indexes:

- forename: nameRef, placeRef
- forenameLength: nameRef, length

forename + forenameLength are indexed on *nameRef* and this index is used to quickly join them. If I extend forenameLength index to cover nameRef, length MySQL does not use the index for the condition `forenameLength.length = 3`.

Is there any way allow the index to be used for the where condition?

If I change the query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM forename
JOIN forenameLength ON forenameLength.nameRef = 1 # change
WHERE forename.placeRef = 18000 AND forenameLength.length = 3
```

i.e. the join is fixed, it then uses the index for the where condition `forenameLength.length = 3`.

Tabe outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE `forenameLength` (
  `nameRef` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `length` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `forenameLength`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`nameRef`,`length`) USING BTREE;
  
  CREATE TABLE `forename` (
  `random` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `placeRef` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `nameRef` int(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `forename`
  ADD KEY `placeRef` (`placeRef`,`nameRef`) USING BTREE;
```

Explain for 1st query:

[image]

***the occurrence of using where is what I am trying to solve***

Using where is caused by `forenameLength.nameRef = forename.nameRef`. As mentioned changing it to `forenameLength.nameRef = 1` removed using where from EXPLAIN. This second query (from above) provides the EXPLAIN:

[image]

UPDATE: Is it possible someone could comment - is it normal behaviour that an index on more than one column (as above) uses an index on a join, but not on where? I have been working on this for days, with no luck, no leads.

Comment: you can't compare both queries. your second searches for 1 partcular id which can be found easily, vut the first needs to compre every row of it fits for all ids.

Comment: You did not include the EXPLAIN for the second query yet.

Comment: Could it be an issue that I do not have unique rows in the forename table? I am reading this can cause issues.

Comment: Why have `forenameLength`?  Why not simply have the `length` in the other table?

Comment: @RickJames - this is being used to query multiple facets about the names, length, commonality etc. So having them all in the same table would require copious indexes.

Comment: @KohjahBreese - The way you have the schema, you need `nameRef` in an index.